# xsl using xml to text format

Tags: xml, xslt

i am trying to convert xml to text format by using xsl  i got output but some dono to adjust value

xml:

```
<xx>
    <yy id="1">
        <aa value="1"/>
    </yy>
    <yy id="2">
        <aa value="1"/>
    </yy>
    <yy id="3">
        <aa value="11"/>
    </yy>
    </xx>
```

xsl :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"  
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="/">

      <xsl:text>Id</xsl:text><xsl:text>     </xsl:text>Number 

     <xsl:for-each select="xx/yy">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@id"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each>


     <xsl:for-each select="xx/yy/aa">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="@value"/><xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
     </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

out-put are:

```
id      number

1
2
3
1 1 11
```

but desried out are

```
id      number

1        1
2        1
3        11
```

am new to xslt how to achieve this format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to achieve your desired output you should remove second `for-each` loop and move output of value from it into first loop.

So your loop should look like:

```
<xsl:for-each select="xx/yy">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@id"/>
    <xsl:text>    </xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="aa/@value"/>
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Note I've changed `select` in the second output to `aa/@value` in order to get child node `aa` value.